# How to display localized time from datetime in django template

Tags: python, django, datetime, django-templates

To be brief.
`next_contact` is a UTC datetime
When I write in template

```
{{ event.next_contact }}
```

I get properly localized date and time
But in this place I want output only time so I do:

```
{{ event.next_contact.time }}
```

and then I get non localized time

How to fix it??

Comment: Maybe [docs about timezones](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/timezones/#time-zone-aware-output-in-templates) help a bit.

Comment: following your suggestion I tried `{{ event.next_contact.time|localtime }}` after `{% load tz %}` but it outputs empty string -  think because .time does not store time zone info

Comment: Something like `{{ event.next_contact|localtime|date:"H:i" }}` should work.

Comment: Yep is does. I just think too much python... And localtime is not necessary in my case - i got 'USE_TZ=True' in settings

Comment: Maybe post it as an answer... It's your credit...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `{{ event.next_contact|localtime|date:"H:i" }}`. If you have set `USE_TZ=True` you can skip the `localtime` filter.

As of [Django 1.7](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/releases/1.7/) when passed a datetime value with attached timezone information (a time-zone-aware datetime instance) the [`time` filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/templates/builtins/#std%3atemplatefilter-time)  will accept the timezone-related format specifiers 'e', 'O' , 'T' and 'Z'.

Answer (score 5):

Instead of using the attribute, just use the `time` filter on the datetime:

```
{{ event.next_contact|time }}
```